# SWIFT: Constraint break in landscape mode when layout has ScrollView and ImageView

Tags: ios, swift

Building a iOS app, where in a view the user is allowed to pinch and zoom the image.
On startup, the image is displayed fitting to the screen.
Have a layout with ImageView and ScrollView and its layout is defined as follows:

```
private func setup() {
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
```

The code works fine but on switching to landscape mode following errors are raised:

```
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-04-08 17:19:53.006762-0700 AcvMagicEye[16556:6738323] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28119f020 UIView:0x102bac310.height == 63.2   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2811a6bc0 UIView:0x102bac310.height == 284   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2811a6bc0 UIView:0x102bac310.height == 284   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Have tried commenting out some of the constraints but then it causes the image to be zoomed out instead of fitting the image to display and then allowing user to scroll and zoom it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false for imageView and scrollview

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

private let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
private let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "jupiter"))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setup()
}

private func setup() {

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),

        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
    ])
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you forgot to add translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false to both scrollview and imageview
2. you use both center X,Y and top,bottom constraints  for the imageview. It also causes to crash.If you are using Center X,Y you should use the width,height constraints.This scenario you have to use top,bottom constraints.

.

```
private func setup() {


    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.delegate = self

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),

        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
}
```